# Select column and filter contents before searching on another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I´m trying to wirte a code and need some help.
I´ve managed to write parts of it using many sources around the web, but got to a point where I can´t find something to use as model or maybe find the right function.

I have an excel workbook with 2 worksheets, on the first one I have data from income and payments. With the code below I´ve managed to sort out the payments by eliminating blank cells from a range on "Plan1" and then copied to the other worsheet - "Plan2"

On Plan2 I get the following results:

[image: Resulting data]

Now, as you may see most of the codes are ending in "01". 
What I need is:

After selecting column C; - done

Get all the values and search for them on Plan1, but removing the trailing "01" from them (since they vary in length) before search and then color the results on Plan1.

Advices please.

**EDIT:** I need to ignore the lines that do not end on "01". The full column will be selected.

Comment: So what you want as your search criteria will be something like `=LEFT(C1,LEN(C1)-2)`.

Comment: Something like it, but how to do that with the whole column selected? How do I replace C1(maybe using =LEFT(Range, LEN(Range)-2), and how to ignore the lines that do not end in "01"?.

Comment: @dwirony that may cause some issues since not all of the cells have '01' appended. For instance 3322 would become 33 and would be searched for. Alex can you clarify if we need to remove the last two from all, or just the '01' cases

Comment: Alex use and IF condition to check if the rightmost two digits are 01, and then replace them with "".

Comment: @shash You're right, I glimpsed at the whole data set - maybe change it to `IF(RIGHT(C1,2)="01",LEFT(C1,LEN(C1)-2),C1)`

Comment: @dwirony Yes I believe that should work too.